# What's the correct ARIA role to use for this color picker widget?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I created [this color picker widget](https://isiahmeadows.github.io/color-picker/), and it features an unusual, mostly mouse-based control scheme manipulating the HSV value:

- Move mouse up to increase brightness (value), down to decrease brightness
- Move mouse left or right to change color (hue)
- Scroll in to increase vividness (saturation)

I was thinking of creating an alternate input for blind and limited-vision users, but because of the 3D slider-like control scheme that doesn't really use a visible slider at all, the `role="slider"` doesn't apply here. So what ARIA role should I use for that kind of 3D "slider" of sorts?

Comment: ARIA roles are important for screen reader users, who rely on the keyboard to use websites. So before thinking about appropriate WAI-ARIA roles, you should make the colour picker widget keyboard accessible. When I looked at the demo, I had no idea how to use it just with a keyboard.

Comment: I agree with @ChristopheStrobbe.  The color picker, while certainly creative, is a bit difficult to understand. That doesn't mean you shouldn't try - we wouldn't have new interfaces such as touch screen phones if Apple didn't try creating a new interface, but the iphone was (mostly) inherently easy to use and understand. Not sure I can say the same about this color picker. Definitely try to make it keyboard usable first and see if you can stay away from creating a separate interface which would segregate your users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a purely theoretical  point of view, this is a replacement for `input[type=color]` tag, so according to [ARIA in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#input-button) it should have no role.

Answer (score 0):

The interaction is effectively that of two different sliders (vertical for brightness and horizontal for hue).

One possible way to make things accessible to screen reader users would be to present two separate sliders in the underlieing HTML, and use the [aria-orientation](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-orientation) attribute to indicate which way each one is presented. You'd then need to make sure the JavaScript provided the relevant keyboard support for each one.

The [ARIA APG](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#slider) has some demos.

If either slider influences the state of the other (if changing the brightness changes the hue for example), then you might need a more complex solution. A variation on the [double slider](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2008/06/aria-slider-part-3/) might be an option. That example/demo is a little old now, but adapting it to use the APG patterns should do the trick.